# From where do I get elementary Freya?

Tags: release-freya

I know Loki is out there and I already have installed that on my laptop. But, for sake of old PCs performance I want to keep last version of Freya.

How could I get the magnet link?

Please do share both 32 and 64 bit versions. Also, it might be last chance for 32bit devices to enjoy elementary OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ashrise tracks their torrents, you can technically download them [there](https://ashrise.com/torrents). There is no official source, as proper support for a release pretty much ends when a new one is made.

Comment: Isn't elementaryOS Freya will be supported till eol of Ubuntu 14.04? Thanks for sharing the link though!

Comment: Ubuntu will support the kernel and underlying infrastructure, but the elementary apps will likely not see significant updates.